# How to set projectionList/ resultTransformer for a @oneToMnay left join in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, projection

I have 3 entities, A, B, C. 
1, A <----> B  
The relationship between A and B is `@OneToOne`
2, A <----> C  
The relationship between A and B is `@OneToMany`
3, B <-X-> C  
The is no relationship between B and C

I already have the entity codes like :

```
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Transient
    private String bData;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    private B b;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private Collection<C> cs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = 'data')
    private String data;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private A a;
}

public class C{
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbdId embdId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId("id")
    private A a;
}

public class EmbdId{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;    

    @Column(name = "another_Id")
    private Integer another_Id;    
}
```

I also have the Criteria and Projection for entity A like this:

```
private Criteria createACriteria() {
        return hibernateDaoMap.get(A).createCriteria("a")
                .setFetchMode("B", FetchMode.SELECT)
                .setFetchMode("C", FetchMode.SELECT)
                .createAlias("a.b", "b", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                .createAlias("a.cs", "cs", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
//not sure if 
                .setProjection(projectionList()
                        .add(property("a.id"), "id")
                        .add(property("b.data"), "bData")
                        .add(property("cs"), "cs")                  
                        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
        }
```

Right now, I have the mapping between A and B working, but the mapping between A and C is not.

When querying `A` by `id`,  I get several instances of `a` returned, but with same id. The number is exactly the number of instances `c` which matched the `id`

What I want is one instance of `a`, but with a set of different `c` in the A entity